# Disconnect from running application in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

When I run an openvpn client connect command, for example:

openvpn --config /path/to/my/ovpn

I get connected to the VPN server but the application session is active so I never get the terminal "back" to me. Basically if I use Ctrl+c to exit I will drop the VPN connection which I don't want to.

How do I run application in such a manner I could easily leave them be and go on in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `&` sign at the end of your command:

`openvpn --config /path/to/my/ovpn &`